# Large(5977x8340) canvas not showing on ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, canvas

I am trying to display a canvas size 5977x8340 on a page and it is showing correctly on desktop and android but not showing on iPhone(safari,chrome). I have tried with less size like 854x1192 and it's working fine.
I have to show canvas with 5977 x 8340 size in iPhone as well. Please help me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Please share some code examples

Comment: var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 5977; 
canvas.height = 8340;

// Create gradient
var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(75, 50, 5, 90, 60, 100);
grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
grd.addColorStop(1, "white");

// Fill with gradient
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 80);

This is sample code where i am passing height and width like above

Comment: Try to use document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width insted of canvas.width let me know if you get error on the log

Comment: ex. code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MZrvJE

Comment: Size is fixed , i can't use getBoundingClientRect